# Is the WolframScript error message "The product exited because of a license error" accurate?

Tags: scripting, automation

I find that sometimes when I use `wolframscript` to run a `.wls` file
(as part of a workflow involving hundreds of such files),
its memory consumption will balloon (>20GB) until I have to kill it.
At that point,
it prints the message `The product exited because of a license error.` to `stderr`.

The log looks no different to the log from successful runs,
which generally use <5GB RAM.

Is it actually a license error that causes the memory explosion,
or is this just what `wolframscript` prints whenever it is killed?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I believe your question is more suitable to be sent directly to [WRI](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback), because we cannot reproduce this issue without any code (and we don't know your license details etc.). If you edit the question and post the code, we can try to help you improve the memory efficency, though ...

Comment: Thanks—I'm currently just looking to know if other people have seen this error in non-license contexts. If it is a licensing issue causing the error then I can pursue that angle; if it's a red herring then I can look for other causes of the memory blowing up and the code hanging.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the following file and ran it with WolframScript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

Pause[10000000000]
```

and ran it with

```bash
wolframscript -file
```

Then switched to another shell and ran

```bash
killall -9 WolframKernel
```

This then gave the same message as above:

```
The product exited because of a license error.
```

From this, it seems that that message is a red herring and one should ignore it, instead looking for other causes of code hanging.

(On the other hand, the message

```
Your Wolfram product is not activated or is experiencing a license-related problem.

Please activate the product at the following WolframKernel location:
```

likely is due to a genuine license problem, and indicates you've started more kernels than you're licensed for, potentially because you've left a Mathematica window open.)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/121227)

Comment: My question was "Is the message accurate". The answer, as stated in more words in my answer, is apparently "no".